# how to save and restore position of map in google map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used Google API version 2 in my previous assignment. There I had used `map.savePosition()` to save the current position of map and `map.returnToSavedPosition()` to restore to the saved position. I have searched for the equivalent in api version 3 documentation but could not find relevant results. And if I use `map.savePosition()` now with api-3, javascript error tells "**map.savePosition is not a function**".

Can someone please tell me what are the ways to save and restore the position of Google Map in API 3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said above, there's no similar function in V3. It's really easy to implement yourself.

Here's one way:

```
var previousPosition;
function savePosition(map) {
  previousPosition = map.getCenter();
}

function returnToSavedPosition(map) {
  if (previousPosition) {
    map.panTo(previousPosition); // or setCenter
  }
}
```

... then just call it like:

```
savePosition(map);
```

Simple, huh?

Comment: savePosition()/restorePosition() in v2 also saved/restored the zoom level.

Comment: Thanks broady for this simple demonstration!

Answer (score 2):

v3 doesn't have a savePosition() function. You need to use getCenter() and getZoom() to retrieve the current position and then restore that position with setCenter() and setZoom().